# EAR does not work from with in the RAD IDE

Tags: deployment, websphere, rad, ear

I have a RAD 7.5 with WAS TE 7.0.0.15 installed on my windows XP 32 bit machine.

I used to be able to open my EAR project and deploy onto the server directly i.e. right click on EAR > Run on server > and then point to my server.

The EAR URL looked like this:
http://localhost:9080/myContext/Login.action

When I deploy the EAR (export as and EAR file first and then install the EAR from admin console) I am able to work with the application just fine.

However,
after trying to use the profiling feature of RAD, this feature has simply stopped working.
I am no longer able to run the application from with in the IDE. I simply get the 404 error. 
I am not able to understand the difference between why it works when deployed as an enterprise application from admin console.

I have uninstalled the server assuming something might have corrupted the server. But it did not help at all.

Is this a known problem?
Please help.

Thanks,
Ayusman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problems of similar nature with RAD 7.5 and WAS 7 runtime. I used it to install, configure and test several our corporate applications. Sadly, sometimes exceptions thrown by these applications caused the server profile, in which they were executed, to corrupt inadvertently, and no cache cleaning/redeploying helped. Deploying via admin console is more stable, as it does not use Eclipse/Websphere integration, which is probably the problem here.

My general advice for working with RAD is this:

- prepare a configuration archive of your application immediately after you configure it (right-click on the server, *Server configuration -> Backup*), **before** you even install it; this will likely come handy later;
- upon problems with starting/stopping the server/application, try stopping (or killing, if it does not stop) the WAS server first, then delete everything from `[yourprofiledir]/temp` and `[yourprofiledir]/wstemp`, then restart the server;
- if the above fails, restore the configuration from the archive (*Server configuration -> Restore*).

If you set up your configuration by scripts, then you probably don't need the archive, as it is not costly then to remove and recreate a server profile — as it's the profile that often gets corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult for me state what the problem is likely to be based on what i see from your post.

Are you sure you are deploying it to the right server? I am just wondering if you have two server run times (one that is used for Profiling) and one for regular testing.

Does RAD show any error when you deploy the application from RAD?

I would still go to the admin console after RAD has performed its publish and see if the application is installed.

I would also look at the logs which should clearly state that the application is installed and started if the publishing from RAD is successful.

Hopefully these give you some idea.

HTH

Manglu

Comment: yes I have a single server runtime only.RAD does not complaint when deploying.In admin console nothing the app shows as deployed and started.Logs do say that the app started, but I keep getting 404 error after that. I can not make anything out of this. But yes, when I deploy it from admin console as an EAR it runs just fine. This problem started after I tried to profile the application (RAD 7.5.0), and yes even the profile does not work. I have confirmed with the IBM partner world folks and they agree I have stumbled across a BUG in 7.5.0 profiling. I think that corrupted something :-(